# Migration MySQL to Mariadb case-sensitive query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have old system using mysql, and now using MariaDB 10.11

```
SELECT AA.CLOSING_ADVICE_ID, AA.CLOSING_ADVICE_NUMBER 
FROM
(
SELECT ca.closing_advice_id,ca.CLOSING_ADVICE_NUMBER,ca.debit_note_id,ca.currency_id,pp.payment_plan_term, (pr.PRODUCTION_NET_PREMIUM * (pp.PAYMENT_PLAN_PERCENTAGE/100)) AS due_to_you 
FROM t_closing_advice ca 
INNER JOIN t_production pr ON ca.closing_advice_id=pr.closing_advice_id 
INNER JOIN t_payment_plan pp ON ca.closing_advice_id=pp.closing_advice_id )AA 
WHERE AA.CLOSING_ADVICE_ID=1500;
```

Please see image below

[NEW - MariaDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcEqz.jpg)
[OLD - MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0oZV.jpg)

If you cant notice behavior not same, i want to get result/output select with UPPERCASE. Any configuration related for this? without change query.

Comment: Have you tried changing the inner `SELECT` to `SELECT ca.CLOSING_ADVICE_ID...`?

Comment: What difference? Do you get another result now?

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner select to:

```
SELECT ca.CLOSING_ADVICE_ID,
```

Or change the outer select to:

```
SELECT AA.CLOSING_ADVICE_ID "CLOSING_ADVICE_ID",
```

Comment: I know just change query lowercase to UPPERCASE. But i ask any configuration related to this behavior mysql old in mariadb new?

Comment: I don't think so; it seems like a bug to me